# TabGroupActivity : WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window

Tags: android, windows, token, android-tabactivity

my app is crashing, when I am going to add Activity which extends TabGroupActivity into TabHost.Fallowing is the code. When I directly add HomePage, everything works fine, But when HomePageTabGroup is added, app unfortunately closed.

MainTabHost.java

```
public class MainTabHost extends TabActivity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.maintabhost);

    final TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();
    //tabHost.getTabWidget().setDividerDrawable(R.drawable.tab_divider);


    // Tab for Home
    TabSpec home = tabHost.newTabSpec("Current Jobs");
    // setting Title and Icon for the Tab
    home.setIndicator("Current Jobs",getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon_home_tab));
    Intent homeIntent = new Intent(MainTabHost.this, HomePageTabGroup.class);
    home.setContent(homeIntent);

   // Adding all TabSpec to TabHost
    tabHost.addTab(home); // Adding home tab

    }
}
```

HomePageTabGroup.java

```
public class HomePageTabGroup extends TabGroupActivity {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    startChildActivity("HomePage", new Intent(HomePageTabGroup.this, HomePage.class));
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

finally I got my answer.

At HomePage, there was a custom Progress Dialog,

```
UmeshCustomProgressHUD.show(HomePage.this,"Loading\nPlease wait!", true,true,this);
```

Everything happened due to above line. I replaced

```
HomePage.this
```

with

```
HomePageTabGroup.ctx,
```

where ctx is defined as static Context in HomePageTabGroup. These two lines of code resolves my issue.